# Long delay before Windows 10 launch screen

Tags: windows-10, boot, delay

When booting I've noticed the past several months an extremely long delay (10-15 seconds) after the intial boot prompts. Just a blank (black) screen, before the Windows launch screen appears.

Just wondering iof this is signalling a potential hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

A hardware issue is usually more evident than just a small pause
in the boot process. Such a delay can be caused naturally by any
number of reasons, chief among them is Windows Update having added
more processing to the boot process.

I suggest to check all available hardware indicators, and if nothing
is found, then to just accept the situation. Below are some suggestions:

- Run `chkdsk`
- Test Windows integrity by running the commands
  [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html)
  and then
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
- Check the SMART attributes of the disk(s)
- Run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for many hours, even
  overnight
- Check the Event Viewer for messages relating to the hardware.

If no warnings are found, there is no need to take any action.

Comment: Also, view Startup processes in Autoruns  and check the *VirusTotal* column. In *Task Manager*, look at  *Startup impact* column.